# Swift 4 Firebase online status update

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I build chat app. I have field in each user table which allow to check if user Online. I use just database reference to get **isOnline** status and update it when pull to refresh. I seen that apps update online status automatically when user open or fold app. How i can do that? Do i need any listener or any framework can help me upgrade my code)) Something like ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift...

P.S sorry for cyrillic text on field **isOnline**) it means Online/Offline
[image]

Comment: The Firebase Database documentation has a section dedicated to this topic. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When application start you can update user online in AppDelegate

**Update user online**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        // status parameter indicate user Online
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            OnlineOfflineService.online(for: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!, status: true){ (success) in

                print("User ==>", success)

            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

**Update user Offline**

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            OnlineOfflineService.online(for: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!, status: false){ (success) in

                print("User ==>", success)
            }
        }
 }
```

**Firebase online and offline update service**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

struct OnlineOfflineService {
    static func online(for uid: String, status: Bool, success: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        //True == Online, False == Offline
        let onlinesRef = Database.database().reference().child(uid).child("isOnline")
        onlinesRef.setValue(status) {(error, _ ) in

            if let error = error {
                assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
                success(false)
            }
            success(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Also you need to take care about user network connection. If user network connection off you just call `OnlineOfflineService` with parameters

Comment: i did the same way... but the problem i have is.. i need to update (pull to refresh) every time to check if user offline or online and i want to find way and update it without update my view every time

Comment: Great idea. I would also add code inside `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` in the AppDelegate.
@HeorhiiHeints for the realtime status, you could add a new listener when reading user. Just use `observe(.childChanged)`, this will trigger each time any data inside user changes.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but if you want to set the online/offline value to false when user closes app, use `.onDisconnectSetValue()`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    setInactivityObservers()

    return true
}

func setInactivityObservers() {
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }

    // get user branch of database
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let usersRef = ref.child("Users")
    let userRef = usersRef.child(user.uid)

    // set "isOnline" branch to true when app launches
    userRef.child("isOnline").setValue(true)

    // set value to false when user terminates app
    userRef.child("isOnline").onDisconnectSetValue(false)
}
```

Comment: Nice one...also I would point out that, if for some reason the variable user is not successfully setup i.e Auth.auth().currentUser == nil. We need to set up the observers later in our code when Auth.auth().currentUser != nil 

Answer (score 0):

First

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

Then manage the "presence"

```
let presenceRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "disconnectmessage");
// Write a string when this client loses connection
presenceRef.onDisconnectSetValue("I disconnected!")
```

Then when the user is disconnected

```
presenceRef.onDisconnectRemoveValue { error, reference in
  if let error = error {
    print("Could not establish onDisconnect event: \(error)")
  }
}
```

And Finally, to detect the status

```
let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
  if snapshot.value as? Bool ?? false {
    print("Connected")
  } else {
    print("Not connected")
  }
})
```

Is it ok now ?

Comment: Same as i told in comment before.. i have working example with update database each time with snapshot, BUT to check if online/offline user... i need  pull screen to refresh my view every time and i want to find way without update my view every time with "pull to refresh"